# hijacking event not working for key up event for ngSelect

Tags: angular

I am trying to handle Shiftkey on `keyup` event.

Added this in the `host:` selector of the component:

```
"(keyup)": "onKeyUp($event)",
```

Added Event Listener as follows:

```
onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.which === 16) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = false;
        window.event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

But still the event is propagating and entering a character equivalent to shift key in the ngSelect.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `keydown.shift` instead of writing the function:

```
<input (keydown.shift)="$event.preventDefault()">
```

if you really want to use the function, then change the following to use `keydown`:

```
"(keydown)": "onKeyUp($event)",
```

Comment: tried that ,the event listener is triggered ,but preventDefault() is not working

Comment: Are you using a combination of key with shift or just the shift key?

Comment: just the shift key

Comment: the event listener is getting triggered ,but preventDefault() is not working though.I added a console.log at the last line of the event listener function.its getting executed and logiing in the console ,but after that still the input is getting entered